# Limit connections to server

Tags: sockets, haskell, websocket, server, haskell-snap-framework

I'd like to limit the connections to the websocket server. Namely to 1. The new client kicks the old client out.

This somewhat represents what I want to do. Taking what is in `messages` and sending it through the websocket. If another client connects or the browser refreshes (which should close the old connection, but doesn't for some reason) there are suddenly 2 connections and only every second message receives at the new client.

I use the snap framework for this.

```
createServer = forkIO $ httpServe defaultConfig app

app = route [("/", runWebSocketsSnap handler)]

handler pending = do
    connection <- acceptRequest pending
    loop connection

loop connection = do
    msg <- takeMVar messages
    sendTextData connection msg

{-# NOINLINE messages #-}
messages = unsafePerformIO newEmptyMVar

sendMessage = putMVar messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two different questions here:

1. how to limit number of connections, so there is at most N clients at the same time;
2. make sure old connection will not live forever after browser refresh;

I think you mean #2. In that case you should check that the connection is alive. The best way to do that is to ping the client periodically, e.g. using [forkPingThread](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.9.6.1/docs/Network-WebSockets.html#v:forkPingThread).

If you really need #1, then you should establish shared `MVar` with `ThreadId` of the current client in it. When new client connects, just [kill](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:killThread) the old one.